# iOS: pointer reference to an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a table view with a search, and search scope buttons with two possible scopes. The table is empty until a search is executed. Each scope has it's own mutable array for the table's data source, we'll say `scopeA_array` and `scopeB_array`. To simplify some methods, I'm trying to create a generic pointer reference to whichever array is the currently active scope. So I tried this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray *tableDataArray;
```

In viewDidLoad, I assign it to the default selected scope.

```
_tableDataArray = _scopeA_array;
```

I can log the memory address of each array, they're both the same.

However, if I execute a search, `_scopeA_array` gets populated. Then in my `numberOfRowsInSection` method, I take the count of `_tableDataArray` but it's empty. I log the addresses again, both are different.

How do I create an array property that just references an array, and always points to the same object in memory even if it changes?

EDIT: A simplified way to test this, with the following lines of code, would like a way for tableDataArray to have the contents of testArray, even though the contents of testArray are assigned after:

```
NSArray *testArray = [NSArray new];
NSArray *tableDataArray = [testArray copy];
testArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"my", @"test", @"array", nil];
NSLog(@"table data array: %@", tableDataArray);
// logs empty array
```

Comment: You're not incrementing the retain count of _scopeA_array ... does it get deallocated before your numberOfRowsInSection call?

Comment: I don't know, how would I do that?

Comment: How do you populate _scopeA_array ?

Comment: It gets loaded with a mutable copy of an array initialized from json data returned from an NSURLRequest.

Comment: Well, I think that's your problem. To keep the same reference for _scopeA_array you should instead use `[_scopeA_array addObjectsFromArray:request_result]`, asuming `request_result` is an array

Comment: Try changing the property to (nonatomic, strong).

Comment: @MikeTaverne doesn't help.

Comment: @marosoaie didn't seem to work. diff memory addresses and still empty.

Comment: Does setting self.tableDataArray make any difference? You have us stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best approach is use a method to return conditionally the array for the current scope. So you just always use this method to populate your UITableView

```
- (NSMutableArray*) tableArray
{
    return [self isScopeA] ? _scopeA_array : _scopeB_array;
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing now, but the point (and the question) was to use a pointer reference, if that's even possible.

Comment: I can't see why would you like to do that rather this. But anyway you should could assign like this self.tableDataArray = _scopeA_array; when you change your scope

Comment: That wouldn't work, because the array gets populated after a search is made, after the scope is changed.

Comment: I think that will work because once you assing to self.tableDataArray, this array is pointing to _scopeA_array and therefore the changes made on _scopeA_array are available through self.tableDataArray

Comment: I misunderstood the answer before, you are right. This is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I create an array property that just references an array, and always points to the same object in memory even if it changes?

If you want to track changes to a variable then you use a pointer to the variable rather than a pointer to a single array instance.  E.g.:

```
@implementation MyController
{
    __strong NSArray* *_currentDataPtr;
    NSArray* _dataA;
    NSArray* _dataB;
}

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _currentDataPtr = &_dataA; // Ensure _currentDataPtr is never NULL
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchScope
{
    switch (searchScope)
    {
        default :
            NSAssert(NO, @"");
        case 0 :
            _currentDataPtr = &_dataA;
            break;
        case 1 :
            _currentDataPtr = &_dataB;
            break;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [*_currentDataPtr count];
}
```

If you want it to be a property then implement a property getter that dereferences the pointer:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray* currentData;

- (NSArray*)currentData { return *_currentDataPtr; }
```

Comment: Tried to implement this but xcode doesn't like the double asterisk in `NSArray* *_currentDataPtr;`, and complains "Pointer to non-const type 'NSArray *' with no explicit ownership." Is that a typo?

Comment: @inorganik It looks like you have to explicitly declare the ownership in that case.  Local variables and instance variables are `__strong` by default.  I've edited my answer.